# How to fix "Unresolved reference" when passing context with this@MapsActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context

**Problem Summary**

- My *main* activity is called **MapsActivity.kt**
- I have a location permission check that is inside **mapFragment.kt**
- When I try to pass the context of **MapsActivity** to the method *isGpsEnable()* which is inside **mapFragment** then I get the error *Unresolved Reference:@MapsActivity*
- I have a splashscreen **SplashActivity.kt** which has the  in the Manifest

*What I have tried*

- The activity **android:name** is **correct** in the manifest
- I have tried both *this@MapsActivity* and *this@SplashActivity*
- Package name is **correct*
- Restart/Invalidate etc
- Used *requireContext()* and it works but don't know if its the **correct** way to solve this
- Call *isGpsEnable()* method in OnMapReady

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="gr.mantis_project.obdLogger">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        <activity
                android:name="gr.example.obdLogger.SplashActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="gr.example.obdLogger.MapsActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MapsActivity.kt

```
package gr.example.obdLogger

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
    override fun onMapReady(p0: GoogleMap?) {
    }
    override fun onMapClick(p0: LatLng?) {
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivitymainBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.mapsactivity)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
    }
```

mapFragment.kt

```
package gr.example.obdLogger

class MapFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var mMapView: MapView
    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var mView: View
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var lastLocation: Location

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        isGpsEnable()  
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)

        mMapView = view?.findViewById(R.id.mapview) as MapView
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this)

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mMapView.onResume()
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true      
    }

    companion object {
        private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    }

    private fun isGpsEnable(): Boolean {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),   // **This works**
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this@MapsActivity, // **This is unresolved**
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            requestPermissions(
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ),
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        } else {
            Log.e("DB", "PERMISSION GRANTED")
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: You are in a Fragment and you can't use `this@MapsActivity`. Use `requireActivity()`. Keep attention if the `Fragment` is not attached to the `Activity`, it will throw `IllegalStateException`

Comment: @Gabriele  Thanks for the reply. so **requireContext** isn't right? Should use **requireActivity()**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no inner dependency from ***MapFragment*** to ***MapsActivity***, so you can not reference MapsActivity as outer reference. An outer reference only works for inner classes (note that lambda functions are anonymous inner clases, therefore you can also use `this@` there to reference the outer scope). If you need a context in your app you can call the nullsafe `requireContext()` method within ***MapFragment*** or reference the instance of ***MapsActivity*** through

```
    (activity as MainActivity)
```

A fragment has access to the activity it is attached to through its property `activity` this why `(activity as MainActivity)` works

When working with nullable values I like using the ? operator chained with a `let`e.g. 
`context?.let{ doStuff(it) }` That way you're safe that you won't get nullptr exceptions

Comment: Thanks Martin. Will stick to the **requireContext()** and slowly try your approach.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. `MapsActivity` isn't the outer scope of your fragment. You can read a bit more about qualified `this` [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified)